# Copy list from one Sharepoint site to another site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a 2007 SharePoint site called Beta.  On Beta, I have a custom List called MapData.  This is a custom list of data that a webpart reads from.  Data has been typed into Beta to make sure the webpart works correctly.

In production, called Prod, I have that same List called MapData except it has old values.  How can I copy the data from one site to another.  Beta and Prod are on different servers.  I would like to do this without writing C# or something.  Is it possible use the command line to just backup that list and restore it on a different server or possibly use Sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following options are not without drawbacks, but they are codeless:

1. If the list is not too large, you can save it as a template, copy the .stp file from Beta to Prod, and create a new list based on the template.
2. STSADM has export/import
3. Gary LaPointe's custom STSADM command for this job: http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/11/import-export-copy-and-delete-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking to sync the two lists. 
I need one to be the data that the public can see, while the other (parent list) has all of the public and private data.